# Why do I get this message in Hmailserver?

Tags: php, email, server, wamp, sendmail

I got this error in hmailserver:

RECEIVED: 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [ip] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see ...

Do I need an SSL Certificate to be able to send emails to Outlook, Gmail, etc...?

**What I have**

So, first things first:

- At this moment I can send emails from my computer using Wamp, PHP, Sendmail, and Hmailserver ONLY to Online Email Generators.
- I can also send to Gmail but it will always go to spam folder because, like Hotmail I get some kind of blocking.
- I'm unable to receive emails from Gmail or Hotmail/Outlook.
- I have set up a no-ip domain name and I can access it from outside.
- In Hmailserver > Advanced > Ip ranges > "Require SMTP Authentication" I have checked all fields
- I have tried both ports 25 and 587.
- Hmailserver > Settings > Protocols > SMTP > Delivery of email tab > I have premiumnews.ddns.net

**What I want to be able to do**

- I want to be able to send many emails to any email service around the world (for legitimate purposes).
- I don't want other ideas like using limited SMTP's like Gmail's, or any other.
- I don't want to use Bulk Mail services.

Comment: Your IP is blacklisted by Spamhaus, to request removal from that list see [the link you removed]. Unless you're on the PBL, then you're never getting off because your ISP told Spamhaus "these IPs will never, _ever_ send legitimate email".

Comment: Ok, but if I remove myself from there, when my ip updates, then I will be there again... And it is actually a bad idea to remove myselft from there, that's at least what I understood by reading spamhaus docs..

Comment: Then don't run your own mail server. Use a service like Sendgrid.